# Sending a string through a thread function to be opened with fopen()

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm taking a string(char *) from a FIFO named pipe, from there I'm putting it in a thread. Once I pass the string(char *) to the thread function, I can print it out just fine. However, if I do

```
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen(string, "wb");

if(fp){
   //it never reaches here
}
```

the entire function is basically as follows for the relevant parts.

```
void *threadFunction(void *stringBuf){
     char *someString;
     someString = (char *) stringBuf;
     printf("%s\n", someString); //prints fine
     FILE *fp;
     fp = fopen(someString, "wb");
     if (fp) {
        //do stuff, but it never reaches here
     }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have write permission to the path specified in `someString`?

Comment: `fopen` can fail, You should report the failure in the `else` part of that `if`. Look up `perror`.

Comment: why you don't look what is the error at fopen ? use perror() !

Comment: adding else part of it, and perror, I get "no such file or directory" which is odd because I'm using "wb" and I thought it would make a file for it?

Comment: @John What is "b" flag ? try to only put "w".

Comment: still the same. No such file or directory

Comment: @John it's not possible. Try a main with `int main(void) { fopen("test", "w"); perror("fopen"); }` you will see that should work. If not you probably don't tell us something.

Comment: I'll do you one better. If I do fopen("test", "wb"); in my thread it works completely fine. But as soon as  I go to add a string instead of typing in a name like that, it doesn't work.

Comment: so I tried opening the stringBuffer inside main, and even that didn't work. I'm getting stringBuffer from a FIFO named pipe. Does that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing obvious in the given code that is specifically thread related that would cause consistent failures.

How is stringBuf allocated in the calling thread?  If it is on the stack it could be overwritten by the calling thread between the printf and the fopen, but you'd expect to see that as an intermittent failure.

Allocate the buffer with malloc() to eliminate this as a possibility.

Comment: in my main stringBuf is defined as  char StringBuffer[MAX_BUF] where MAX_BUF is #define MAX_BUF 1024

Comment: @John - so it is defined on the stack which means that could totally be the problem.  Use malloc to allocate the buffer to eliminate that as a possibility.

Comment: I'm using a named pipe, so I have a function read(fd, stringBuffer, Len); and I'm not sure how to use malloc on this. Really new to C sorry.

Comment: edit made a new string in main and malloc'd it, and then did strcpy(). Still having the same problem. File or directory not found.